# What are the risks of using second hand CPUs and memory modules?

Tags: memory, cpu, hardware-failure

I am a scientist and I want to build a powerful computer with enough RAM to handle large spatial simulations and analyses.

I am thinking about using second hand computer parts and I would like to know what are the specific risks associated with using second hand CPUs and memory modules.

The only thing I know is that CPUs which have been subjected to higher frequencies and voltages through overclocking, have increased [failure rates](http://eurosys2011.cs.uni-salzburg.at/pdf/eurosys2011-nightingale.pdf%22failure%20rates%22). I have not found much other evidence.

Comment: No risks beyond them no working or them failing and be left without a warranty

Comment: Not risks as such, but using older CPU's (and matching older memory) might not actually yields a cost/benefit performance. Do consider that before buying. Also read up on HPC and NUMA (or ask someone who does).

Comment: But an increased failure rate is not a permanent damage and the parts would still work until a failure so I could not know if the parts are actually bad at first. I know about matching memory issues and mobo/memory modules compatibility.

Comment: Additionally to what has been said, I would like to introduce you to Linus Tech Tips' Video-Series Scrapyard-Wars and the recent video on how to build a powerful system with second-hand parts. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL8mG-RkN2uTyuEutQa79RZ0Q5u5gteUci) and [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=epIlB49SNTI) and [maybe here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DN8nmLXXeu4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As always, this depends on the hardware. It is possible that the parts will be flaky, and may not be stable - PARTICULARLY UNDER LOAD - this is more common then it would appear, and a fair chunk of "Blue Screens Of Death" are caused by dodgy hardware.

You (rightly I think) look to overclocking and increased failure rates [ presumably as a risk, and also a proxy for old age ] - Not only does overclocking cause early failure, it definitely [can cause instability](http://www.overclockers.com/forums/showthread.php/335813-Guidelines-for-Thorough-Stability-Testing) as well.

Something to bear in the back of your mind (but possibly not a major concern) but it is possible for older chips to stop or give non-obvious/intermittent problems because of problems with the silicon which only become apparent with age. (I remember a scandal relating to NVIDIA GPUs.  Read [this](http://en.community.dell.com/dell-blogs/direct2dell/b/direct2dell/archive/2008/09/12/nvidia-gpu-update-limited-warranty-enhancement-details) for an example of some problems and how they are intermittent and can be age related.)

That said, a LOT of hardware is discarded when there is nothing wrong with it - it's just too old - so you can pick it up cheaply. Of course you need to balance the hidden costs (electricity usage vs. performance, etc.), and depending on your needs it may or may not be cost-effective to use second-hand equipment.

Comment: +1 for the hidden costs part. I find it fun to build old systems and to toy with them. But fun is another reason than economy.